# Windows UWP ScrollViewer scrollbar overlaps contents

Tags: xaml, uwp, winrt-xaml

[image]

How do you stop a ScrollViewer's scrollbar from overlapping content like this?

I have a RichTextBlock containing text and no matter how wide I make the RichTextBlock, or how I change the Margin and Padding values, I cannot get the scrollbar to move further to the right to stop this overlap from happening. I'm running Windows 10 and it is configured to hide scrollbars until the mouse pointer hovers over them.

Below is the XAML for my app.

```
<Page
    x:Class="PaulWinPOS1.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:PaulWinPOS1"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid Margin="0,26,0,0">
        <Button x:Name="butConnect" Content="Connect" Margin="0,38,48,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-3.274,0.344" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="32" Click="ButConnect_Click" Width="92"/>
        <Button x:Name="butLogin" Content="Login" Margin="0,92,48,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-3.274,0.344" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="32" Width="92" IsEnabled="False" Click="ButLogin_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="butAdd" Content="Add Item" Margin="0,143,48,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-3.274,0.344" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="92" IsEnabled="False" Click="ButAdd_Click"/>

        <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewerWeb" 
            HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
            VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Width="350"
            Padding="16,0"
            Grid.RowSpan="10"
            FontFamily="Segoe UI" RequestedTheme="Dark" ZoomMode="Enabled" 
            Margin="669,304,0,0" >
            <WebView x:Name="webviewReceipt" 
                Margin="10,10,50,10"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                Height="333" Width="300"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" />
        </ScrollViewer>
        
        <Button x:Name="butDisconnect" Content="Disconnect" Margin="0,244,48,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="-3.274,0.344" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="32" Width="92" Click="ButDisconnect_Click"/>


    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The scroll bar of WebView is special and cannot be solved by the conventional ScrollViewer additional properties, but the scroll bar of the WebView can be disabled through the CSS of the web page.

```css
body {
   -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

If you cannot modify the source code of the webpage, you can perform the following operations after the WebView content is loaded:

```cs
private async void webviewReceipt_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{
    string js = "var style = document.createElement('style');" +
               "style.type = 'text/css';" +
               "style.innerHTML = \"body{ -ms-overflow-style: none !important; }\";" +
               "document.getElementsByTagName('Head').item(0).appendChild(style); ";
    await webviewReceipt.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { js });
}
```

---

**Update**

If we need to display a scroll bar, we can add a `padding-right` to the body so that the scroll bar does not block the content.

```cs
private async void webviewReceipt_DOMContentLoaded(WebView sender, WebViewDOMContentLoadedEventArgs args)
{
    string js = "var style = document.createElement('style');" +
               "style.type = 'text/css';" +
               "style.innerHTML = \"body{ padding-right: 24px; }\";" +
               "document.getElementsByTagName('Head').item(0).appendChild(style); ";
    await webviewReceipt.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { js });
}
```

Comment: Zhang That is interesting - the scrollbar completely disappeared with your suggestion. I would prefer the scroll bar to stay onscreen as it gives an indication of how much text is there.

Comment: Hello, currently, the scroll bar of WebView cannot be customized. If you plan to keep the scroll bar, then use the same method of injecting css and add a `padding-right` to the body to separate the content from the scroll bar

Comment: Zhang what you just suggested worked perfectly. I'll accept your answer - you may just want to update it in case somebody else looks at this question for an answer. Thanks heaps!

Comment: Thanks for your reminder, I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `Padding` to `ScrollViewer`.

```
<ScrollViewer Padding="18, 0">
    <RichTextBlock />
</ScrollViewer>
```

Usually the `ScrollBar` Width is 18.

Comment: I already have padding in the question. Changing it from 16 to 18 made no difference either. Perhaps the second ScrollViewer confused things - I've just removed it to make it clearer

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have the scroll bars enabled on both the web view and scroll viewer. You can try disabling the scroll bars on one of them to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Sorry, it's actually the WebView that has the issue, not the RichTextBlock. I removed the second ScrollViewer from the question to avoid confusion

Comment: I think the padding is not showing up correctly because you have the scroll bars turned on for both the scroll viewer and web view. Does it work to disable them in the web view?

Comment: Exactly the same I'm afraid. At least it still scrolls OK without those 2 ScrollViewer.Blah lines